# How to find the largest sum of a list of integers in python starting from any index and end at any ending index without sorting

Tags: python

For example if I have a list [50, 50, -50, -50, -50, 50, 50, -50, 50, 50, 50, -50]

The largest sum would be 200 which is from index 5 to index 10 of that list

How do I do it with dynamic programming using python?

my code is:

```
myList=[50, 50, -50, -50, -50, 50, 50, -50, 50, 50, 50, -50]
answer=[0]
counter=0
for i in range(len(myList)):
    for j in range (i,len(myList)):
        counter+=myList[j]
        if counter>answer[0]:
            answer.insert(0,counter)
    counter=0
print(answer[0])
```

but it is too slow

Comment: Do the numbers have to be consecutive in the list?

Comment: The index has to be consecutive

Comment: @SuperMage_03 Welcome to SO, we are here you help you out , but we can't help you unless you have put some effort in solving this. Please share what you have done so far in solving this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as the Maximum Subarray problem. Its [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane's_algorithm) has a DP solution implemented in Python.